# How does Sharepoint Online Event Receivers work?

Tags: event-handlers, sharepoint-online

I have created this Sandboxed Event Receiver on ItemAdding on a custom list.

It works on my on-premise server, but it does not work on Sharepoint Online aka. O365.

Anybody know how to create an Event Receiver in Sharepoint Online, I will be really thankful!

----- EDIT ----

```
using System;
using System.Security.Permissions;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Security;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow;

namespace Change_Title_Event.Change_Title
{
    /// <summary>
    /// List Item Events
    /// </summary>
    public class Change_Title : SPItemEventReceiver
    {
       /// <summary>
       /// An item is being added.
       /// </summary>
       public override void ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties)
       {
           properties.AfterProperties["Title"] = "Kevin: Changed by event receiver at" + DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.ToString();
           base.ItemAdding(properties);
       }


    }
}
```

Elements.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Receivers ListTemplateId="100">
      <Receiver>
        <Name>Change_TitleItemAdding</Name>
        <Type>ItemAdding</Type>
        <Assembly>$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$</Assembly>
        <Class>Change_Title_Event.Change_Title.Change_Title</Class>
        <SequenceNumber>10000</SequenceNumber>
      </Receiver>

  </Receivers>
</Elements>
```

Scope is Web and the Item is in the Feature.

-------- EDIT 2 ----------

```
using System;
using System.Security.Permissions;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Security;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow;

namespace Change_Title_Event.Change_Title
{
    /// <summary>
    /// List Item Events
    /// </summary>
    public class Change_Title : SPItemEventReceiver
    {
       /// <summary>
       /// An item was added
       /// </summary>
       public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
       {
           base.ItemAdded(properties);
           properties.ListItem["Title"] = "Kevin: Changed by event receiver at" + DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.ToString();
           properties.ListItem.Update();
       }


    }
}
```

This code works on on-premise, but do not work on Sharepoint Online.

Does somebody has a working solution (.wsp), that works on Sharepoint Online?

Comment: You might want to add logging so you can actually see what's going wrong: http://spsl.codeplex.com/.

Comment: There must be a bug on Sharepoint Online, my friend who is an exp. sharepoint programmer also has the problem with event receivers.

Comment: I use SharePoint Online too on a fairly regular basis, don't know of any bugs with event receivers. But a small error can cause a lot of trouble without you knowing if you don't implement any kind of logging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your event receiver is working on your on-premise server, there is no reason it should not work on Office 365. Unless you are doing something from the Event Receiver which is not allowed in Sandbox. In that case, a SPException will be thrown.

There is really no "different" way to create Event Receivers for SharePoint online. I think that your Event Receiver might be firing, but there must be some error in the code for the Event Receiver. Can you please update your answer with code so that it would be easier to find out what might be going wrong?

**Update:**

Can you try the following code?

```
 public override void ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties)
   {
       base.ItemAdding(properties);
       properties.ListItem["Title"] = "Kevin: Changed by event receiver at" + DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.ToString();
       properties.ListItem.Update();
   }
```

Also, is there a reason why you are using the ItemAdd**ing** event instead of the ItemAdd**ed** event?

Comment: I have added the code, it simply changes the title.

Comment: Please see if my updated answer helps.

Comment: I have tried your code, and that only works with ItemAdded. The reason i am using ItemAdding is when you use that, the user see the result immediately. I have updated my post with the new code.

Comment: You can make the item added synchronous. Then the user will see the results immediately. Just add the <Synchronization> element in your Elements.xml. Have a look here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/unsharepoint/archive/2010/11/10/sharepoint-event-receivers-making-asynchronous-event-synchronous-to-avoid-save-conflict-error.aspx

Comment: There must be a bug on Sharepoint Online, my friend who is an exp. sharepoint programmer also has the problem with event receivers.

Comment: Weird. I have used Event Receivers without any problem in SharePoint Online. Did you try with the <Synchronization> element?

Comment: @VardhamanDeshpande, My background with SP is to develop SPO add-ins. Actually, your codes in your blog helped me a lot, specially for CSOM batching. Could you please provide me a simple 3-4 do-this-do-that steps for implementing ER in SPO? Do I deploy as .wsp file and install in the spo? Thank you in advance. Or it could be a link to any url

Comment: @egidiocs This answer was from 4 years ago and since then Microsoft has deprecated use of Server side (sandbox) code in SharePoint Online. This means the above answer is out of date now.  You can however use "Remote Event Receivers" in SPO via SharePoint Add-Ins https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220043.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if it is because of your using references ?  Try cutting your references and using statements to the bare minimum you need.

Comment: What references should i cut? I am using the "Add item" in visual basic to create my event receiver and that is what visual studio puts in.

Comment: There must be a bug on Sharepoint Online, my friend who is an exp. sharepoint programmer also has the problem with event receivers.

Answer (score 0):

I think, in your code
`properties.ListItem.Update();` will throw error during `ItemAdding` Event.

Kevin,

I am able to see that in EDIT-2 you are using `ItemAdded` event, but in element.xml you have missed to input receiver for the same.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to do GetItemByID on your list. and then update it.

```
public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
        {

this.EventFiringEnabled = false;
            base.ItemAdded(properties);

            SPList emp = properties.Web.Lists.TryGetList(Constants.PFSListCollectors);
            SPListItem item = emp.GetItemById(properties.ListItemId);

                item[Constants.ColNameCollectorsName] = Convert.ToString(item[Constants.ColNameName]).Split('#')[1];
                item.Update();

            this.EventFiringEnabled = true;
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

in Elements.xml File Clange **Receivers ListTemplateId="100"** by:

**Receivers ListUrl="YourSubsitename/CustomListName"**

Also Activate the Feature in Manage Site Features