# How to handle Events in SharePoint 2013 On line custom list?

Tags: sharepoint-online, event-receivers

I am working on SharePoint 2013 on line. 
I would like to know best possible way for Event handling in SharePoint 2013 On line.In SharePoint 2010 we manage it through Event Receiver or workflow.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft is going to deprecate Sandbox solutions, so you shouldn't consider it for new development.

**Visual Studio Options -**

Remote/app event receiver is one option, explorer more on this [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220048(v=office.15).aspx). However, you also have the option of Visual Studio [SharePoint Workflow App](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn456545(v=office.15).aspx)

**No code solution -**

If you are not comfortable with Visual Studio programming then you can try SharePoint Designer 2013 Workflows.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Sandbox solution to add event receivers to your custom list. The other option would be using Remote event receivers if you are using any app model.

[How does Sharepoint Online Event Receivers work?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/41303/how-does-sharepoint-online-event-receivers-work)

http://blog.kloud.com.au/2014/03/13/remote-event-receiver-rer-for-host-web-using-sharepoint-provider-hosted-app-in-office-365sharepoint-online-environment/

http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/t/60731.aspx